# upload multiple image and associate to property

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am using django rest framework for rest api. I am trying to work on mutiple image upload and associate those multiple images to property. However my browsable api does not show form to upload the images so i can test if my code works or not. How can i upload multiple image and associate them to property?

```
class Property(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
  address = models.CharField(_('Address'), max_length=140)
  rooms = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(_('Rooms'))

class Gallery(models.Model):
    property = models.ForeignKey(Property, related_name="gallery")
    caption = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=80)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="properties/rooms/")

class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields=('id', 'caption', 'image', )

class PropertySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer, EagerLoadingMixin):
    _SELECT_RELATED_FIELDS = ['owner', ]
    _PREFETCH_RELATED_FIELDS = ['property_type',]
    gallery = GallerySerializer(many=True)


class PropertyGallery(APIView):
    serializer_class = GallerySerializer
    parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
    def put(self, request, property_id=None, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, partial=True)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.errors, status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)

url(r'^upload/images/(?P<property_id>[0-9]*)/$', views.PropertyGallery.as_view(), name='property-gallery'),
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the line,

```
parser_classes = (FileUploadParser,)
```

the serializer fields would be shown.

Since, you have written a view updating existing objects, you may need to raise exception if an object doesn't exist with a particular id. You could use the shortcut function `get_object_or_404()` for that.

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

def put(self, request, property_id=None, format=None):
    _property = get_object_or_404(Property, id=property_id)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, partial=True)
    if not serializer.is_valid():
        return Response(serializer.errors, status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    else:
        serializer.save(property=_property)
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: DRF 3 has deprecated the request.FILES in favor of request.data property.

Comment: Yeah. I missed that. Thanks for notifying. Does the serializer fields are showing when the parser_classes attribute is removed?

Comment: Yeah its showing. But i could not associate the multiple images to Property.

Comment: I have marked your solution as helpful and solved. Can you please change your Note part?

Comment: I'll edit my answer shortly with the association part.

Comment: I have also posted the answer but mine one is not better version. I await your response for better version of association part. Thanks for your help once again

Comment: I have tested the code for single image upload which works perfectly but does this works for multiple image too? I am not getting to select multiple files in browsable api

Answer (score 1):

I am posting a solution of associating multiple images to property. This one is a working code but the code need much more attention. Please feel free to make the following code better.

```
class GallerySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Gallery
        fields=('id', 'caption', 'image', )

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        print ('serializer', serializer)
        serializer.save(property_instance_id=serializer.validated_data['property_id']) #property_instance_id is because i have changed the name property to property_instance in Gallery model as property is the reserved keyword

class PropertyGallery(APIView):
    serializer_class = GallerySerializer
    parser_classes = (FormParser, MultiPartParser, )
    def put(self, request, property_id=None, format=None):
        serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data, partial=True)
        if not serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.errors, status= status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            serializer.save(property_instance_id=property_id)
            return Response(serializer.data, status= status.HTTP_200_OK)
```